# MS Graph API - Create Online Meeting, not generating with dial-in/conference information

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am calling to the MS Graph API to generate a Teams meeting, I previously was doing this same thing but with Application permissions, which MS has decided to deprecate. So I am now setting things up to do this call using User permissions, the new correct way to do it.

I finally got the call itself working in my environment, however I am only getting a URL to join the meeting, no Dial-in or Conference ID so that users can call in from a phone. I've ensured that the account I'm using to generate the meetings is set up with a license for Teams and a Microsoft Audio Conferencing license, but still cannot get Audio Conferencing to return anything other than NULL in the return.

Here's the call I am making to the /beta/me/onlineMeetings endpoint

```
POST /beta/me/onlineMeetings HTTP/1.1 
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer (Token Removed)

{
"startDateTime":"2020-04-14T13:38:34.2444915-07:00",
"endDateTime":"2020-04-14T15:00:34.2464912-07:00",
"subject":"User Token Meeting"
}
```

And here is the main body of the result I get back from Graph:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('REDACTED')/onlineMeetings/$entity",
    "id": "REDACTED":meeting_NTMyZDEwMzYtY2NmZC00MzVlLTgxNDQtZjYxNDJhYjUxNTY4@thread.v2",
    "creationDateTime": "2020-04-14T19:38:11.4760719Z",
    "startDateTime": "2020-04-14T20:38:34.2444915Z",
    "endDateTime": "2020-04-14T22:00:34.2464912Z",
    "joinUrl": "REDACTED URL",
    "joinWebUrl": "REDACTED URL",
    "subject": "User Token Meeting",
    "isBroadcast": false,
    "autoAdmittedUsers": "Everyone",
    "outerMeetingAutoAdmittedUsers": null,
    "capabilities": [],
    "videoTeleconferenceId": "REDACTED",
    "externalId": null,
    "audioConferencing": null,
    "meetingInfo": null,
    "participants": {
        "organizer": {
            "upn": "REDACTED UPN",
            "identity": {
                "phone": null,
                "guest": null,
                "encrypted": null,
                "onPremises": null,
                "applicationInstance": null,
                "application": null,
                "device": null,
                "user": {
                    "id": "REDACTED USER ID",
                    "displayName": null,
                    "tenantId": "REDACTED TENANT ID",
                    "identityProvider": "AAD"
```

Just curious if anyone else is using this call and running into the same issues, or if you know if I need to specify anything in the actual call to Graph to tell it to generate Audio Conferencing as well?

Comment: We are checking this issue with internal team, will let you know once we receive any aupdate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be working now. My best guess is that I hadn't given the Audio Conferencing license enough time to replicate in our environment.